# Can't install Manjaro to a PC using repair stick of a different system

Tags: boot, grub, manjaro

I wanted to install Manjaro on my old P51 work PC but I fail to get started properly.

I created a Manjaro boot USB stick with another Manjaro PC using the disk utility and the restore disk functionality. I then entered the BIOS of the P51 and disabled secure boot and now I'm facing the following screen:

```
error: unkown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd1)
```

Other ppl with this problem seem to have entries like `(hd0.msdos0)` but I don't. Shouldn't I be able to maybe fix the MBR or just install Manjaro? The disks of the system contain no data that needs to be retained.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restore disk isn't an installer for a new system. It's used to restore the system it was created in if there's a catastrophic failure.

To create an installer for a new system in Linux simply use `dd`.

1. Download the distro's .iso file
2. Create the disk with command

```
    sudo dd if=filename.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress
```

The USB stick needs to be umounted to be written with `dd`.

Replace /sdX with the actual USB stick, and please note that you need to refer to the disk itself `/dev/sdX`, not a partition `/dev/sdX1`. You can find the correct device identifier for example with commands `lsblk` or `df` (among others).